# Custom Conventions in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, entity-framework-6

I want to create a convention where EF can serialise `IEnumerable<String>` to a format ( say comma separated values ) and store them in a column and while fetching them back create an `IEnumerable<String>` again.

The msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx mentions the following example

```
class DateTimeColumnTypeConvention : IConfigurationConvention<PropertyInfo, DateTimePropertyConfiguration>
{
    public void Apply(
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func<DateTimePropertyConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        // If ColumnType hasn't been configured...
        if (configuration().ColumnType == null)
        {
            configuration().ColumnType = "datetime2";
        }
    }
}
```

But I would need something like

```
class DateTimeColumnTypeConvention : IConfigurationConvention<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<string>>
   {
       public void Apply(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func<IEnumerable<string>> configuration)
        {
           // Get all the values of the property here, create a comma separated string ,ask EF to store this string by setting the ColumnType to varchar and then get it back.
        }
    }
```

I am unable to locate any obvious way of doing this. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why not leave the responsibility of CRUDs as a CSV to EF and have a Data Logic Tier have the responsibility of transforming it to you desired collection type?

Comment: the point is not CRUD, I would end up repeating the same code across my entire DataLogic Layer, if there were several Entities with the type whose configuration I want to manage through a CustomConvention .

Comment: @JefferyKhan Even as an academic exercise to test the limits of what can be done this should be an interesting problem to solve :)

Comment: The question is: Can you do that through mapping? Conventions do not offer anything additional to the mapping they just offer global way (or attribute controlled way) to do something which is possible with fluent mapping configuration.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka How would I do this through a mapping ? The task is still the same although confined to the Entity. I am however looking for a global solution since I would like to store my IE<String> as a comma separated list.

Comment: That is the point - you will not do that in mapping. It is currently not supported without some logic outside of the mapping (either in entity or in the context).

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yes I am aware of the lack of support, and assuming that I wanted to do it somewhere. the question is how (my question ) and possibly where ?

Comment: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2639292-support-for-simple-type-mapping-or-mapped-type-con